# map2/walk2 – what to do if the input lists are not the first two arguments of the function?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am iterating over two lists/vectors using `walk2` from `purrr`. However, .x and .y are not the first two arguments of the function - `write_tsv` in this case. I have got around it by generating an anonymous function, but I'm not sure if this is the best way?

```
walk2(TCR_donor_cell, names(TCR_donor_cell),
      ~ write_tsv(.x, file = paste0("results/TCR/", .y, "_paired_chains.txt")))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `iwalk` if the intention is to make it compact

```
library(purrr)
iwalk(TCR_donor_cell, ~ write_tsv(.x, file =
     file.path('results/TCR', paste0(.y, '_paired_chains.txt'))))
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't used I walk before. Is there any reason you included `file.path` rather than just `iwalk(TCR_donor_cell, ~ write_tsv(.x, file = paste0('results/TCR/', .y, '_paired_chains.txt')))`?

Comment: @Lucy It is just that `file.path` can work in most of the OS

Comment: I was imagining something more like `map2(TCR_donor, names(TCR_donor_cell), write_tsv, paste0('results/TCR/', .y, '_paired_chains.txt'))` with the elements of TCR_donor_cell automatically becoming the first argument of `write_tsv`

Comment: @Lucy The `.y` without the lambda expression (`~`) wouldn't work

Comment: Ok thank you, I was just wondering whether there was a way using a pre-defined function without having to generate a new lambda function.

Comment: @Lucy You can create a function i.e. `f1 <- function(x, y) write_tsv(x, file = file.path('result/TCR', paste0(y, '_paired_chains.txt'))); then just use `iwalk(TCR_donor_cell, f1)`